# How to make a exit button on Ionic 4 cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4

I have tried to create a button to exit, and none of them works. What would be the correct way to do it on Ionic 4 with Cordova?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using **navigator[‘app’].exitApp()**..
or if you are willing to use cordova **cordova.plugins.exit()**

Answer (score 0):

just providing an example ... even though the app "exit" - when clicking on the background tasks - i still see it .. :/

```
  # home.page.html
  <ion-button (click)="exitApp()" color="danger">
    Exit App
  </ion-button>

  # home.page.ts
  exitApp() {
    navigator['app'].exitApp();
  }
```